# Compile rosmatlab with winros, or what is catkin_make_isolated?

Tags: ros, catkin-make-isolated, rosmatlab, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm compiling rosmatlab by the TU Darmstadt from source using winros. I already got to install it correctly in a Ubuntu environment with "original" ROS installed and I also got winros working on Windows 7. Now I'm following [the steps](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/rosmatlab/wiki/Installation) I did to install rosmatlab on the Ubuntu system and am faced with a command called `catkin_make_isolated` which is described in section 3 (ROS) in the linked document.
Unfortunately, this command hasn't been rebuilt for winros and I don't even know how it actually differs from catkin_make. Can anybody tell me briefly what the differences are? Is it "easy" to find a workaround that works with catkin_make or should I take another approach on this?

Every suggestion is well appreciated.
Greets, Roberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144141/compile-rosmatlab-with-winros,-or-what-is-catkin_make_isolated?/) by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of winros, catkin_make and catkin_make_isolated are just simple wrappers around callouts to cmake to build the projects. The first two, winros, catkin_make make a single cmake project of your entire source workspace. The latter, makes a cmake project for every package in your source workspace.

There is a REP explaining catkin_make_isolated in detail: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0134.html

You can also check the scripting for catkin_make_isolated (it's not too hard) in this function: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/indigo-devel/python/catkin/builder.py#L636.

The next question is, why use catkin_make_isolated? The main reason is to be able to build conventional cmake projects alongside catkin packages. What conventional cmake projects is rosmatlab trying to build? Perhaps they can be built and installed separately prior to a regular winros/catkin_make?

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on 2014-03-26**:
Thanks for your answer! The main reason why I considered using catkin_make_isolated is that it's described in the installation guide of rosmatlab. It's at the point where I want to compile ROS with another version of the boost libraries. But, as I realized while writing the answers to your questions, I don't need to build ROS, but winros, so the real question would be how I can compile winros with another version of the boost libraries.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-03-26**:
The scripts win_ros uses to build boost 1.47 are clean.bat, download.bat, make.bat in https://github.com/ros-windows/win_ros/tree/hydro-devel/rosdeps/win_boost. This is cmake boost. You could change the download branch to 1.44 (it exists) and see how that goes (ymmv).